# Summarize fields in a table

Tags: abap

I have to write a code with summarizes a field. I have a data like this

```
AAA BBB CCC 1
AAA BBB CCC 2
        SUM 3
-------------
DDD EEE FFF 3
GGG HHH III 4
        SUM 7
-------------
     TOTAL 10
```

So i have to summarize fields SUM into one SUM, but the problem is that those are not two variables, it a one variable, and the code loop trough the table and fills the field SUM called G_SUM, so how to make a total sum, I cannot write sum + sum because it's only one field...

Comment: Declare a local variable (e.g. `TOTAL_SUM`) and add `SUM` to it on each iteration? Why isn't that possible exactly?

Comment: Ok, can you please write the code, I'm totally new in ABAP. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stackoverflow.com ist not a write-my-code-for-me service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you outputting in ALV format?  If so, there are built in aggregate functions.

in the field catalog structure, pass do_sum = 'X'.

Also, you need to add a sort structure, and pass subtot = 'X'.

Of course, if your output is simple write statements, you will need to write the code yourself as mentioned in some of the other comments.